# How to center Lyx-code?

Tags: lyx

I think that my 2 problems are easier to explain with an example, so here is the Lyx preview of it.

[image]

CODE:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing onehalf
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 4
\tocdepth 4
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
As you can see below I have written some Python code that only skips the
 right margin.
 The code respects the left margin though, which makes it look like it is
 shifted to the right.
 Is there a way to make it look more centered?
\end_layout

\begin_layout LyX-Code
class HelloWorld:
\end_layout

\begin_layout LyX-Code
    def __init__(self):
\end_layout

\begin_layout LyX-Code
        self.very_long_variable_name_that_goes_outside_of_margin = 'I am
 very long'
\end_layout

\begin_layout LyX-Code
    def repeat_hello_world(self, number_of_repeats):
\end_layout

\begin_layout LyX-Code
        self.number_of_repeats = number_of_repeats
\end_layout

\begin_layout LyX-Code
        for i in range(self.number_of_repeats):
\end_layout

\begin_layout LyX-Code
            print(self.very_long_variable_name_that_goes_outside_of_margin)
\end_layout

\begin_layout LyX-Code
            print('Hello World')
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
The other problem that I have is that I want the line spacing of all the
 text except the code to be 1.5, but then the linespacing of the code also
 becomes 1,5.
 Can you have different parts of the document with different line spacings?
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you show us the TeX code resulting in your screenshot please?

Comment: I don't have any TeX code, I only use Lyx

Comment: Please read here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: Also, are you using Insert > Program Listing to put your code into?

Comment: Lyx can show you the used TeX code to create the pdf file. How it does it I do not know, sorry, I'm not a Lyx user ...

Comment: @scottkosty, no, I am using the 'Lyx-code' environment

Comment: @Unnamed ah, now I see you had already put that. Thanks.

Comment: Your problem would be easier to understand (and much more findable by internet search engines) if you would [edit] the text into the question, instead of hiding it in an image of the output you created.

Comment: I don't understand your "Lyx-code environment" comment.  Do you not have a .lyx file like the MWE page talks about?  (It doesn't help that most of us don't use Lyx.)

Comment: @Teepeemm In Lyx there are several environments: Title, Section, Subsection, Paragraph, Standard... One of them is called 'Lyx-code', and it lets you type code without any restrictions such as double spaces, which are not allowed in default text.

Comment: @Teepeemm, yes I have a .lyx file like the MWE page talks about, but how can I share it with you?

Comment: That is also covered in the MWE link that scottkosty posted: open the .lyx file in Notepad and copy/paste.  But please try to cut your .lyx file down to as small as possible before sharing it.

Comment: Right, I've added everything I have

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130133/discussion-between-unnamed-and-teepeemm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some chatting, it seems that OP's problem was solved with some help from https://stackoverflow.com/q/2116944/2336725 and the package `listings` in order to have some color.