# How to remove page break before and after inserting PDF?

Tags: lyx, pdf

I have a document in Lyx where I need to insert a PDF file in a similar way as this example. First I have a paragraph of text (in these pictures it is randomly generated), then I insert a PDF file using Insert > File > External Material (in this example it is a PDF file of the Wikipedia article about bees), and then I have another paragraph.

However, the PDF leaves a very long blank space after the first paragraph and another blank space before the second paragraph. Is there a way to fix it?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Note: I only use Lyx, not LaTeX, I don't have the LaTeX code

Comment: Is your inserted pdf pages 2 and 3 of your example?  That looks like it's inserting the pages in their entirety, which I would expect to be the default behavior.  Are you sure you're wanting to insert a pdf, and not actually the *text* of that pdf?

Comment: Yes, my inserted pages are pages 2&3.

Comment: And I also want to insert the PDF, not the text

Comment: But the pdf is those two full pages.  What are you wanting to be in the blank area at the bottom of page 1?  The top half of the first page of the pdf?  What are you wanting to be in the blank area at the bottom of page 3, which is a part of the pdf?

Comment: I want the PDF file to start right after the first paragraph, so it has to be split

Comment: you are inserting pages, basically as uneditable blocks that are inserted into the latex generated pdf they do not take part in the normal text flow and page breaking, it's like slotting in two extra pages after the document is finished. You will need to arrange to input them at a suitable place.

Comment: You can try to figure out the cropping in order to insert part of the first pdf page at the bottom of page 1, parts of pdf pages 1 and 2 sharing page 2, and the rest of pdf page 2 at the top of page 3.  But it won't be easy (maybe impossible with Lyx), and the result won't look at all nice.

Comment: Alright. This problem comes from this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617071/how-to-center-lyx-code, where I couldn't properly align the code so I decided to use PDFs. Which solution do you think is easier?

Comment: the system you are using is for inserting pages extracted from another publication, it doesn't really make sense to use it for text that you are writing as part of this document unless they need to be separate pages,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The text that I am inserting is not from another publication, it is written by me. It had to be aligned in a different way than the rest of the text, but I couldn't do it, so instead I aligned it in a different document, saved it as a PDF and tried to insert it to the first one.

Comment: but as I said you have then formatted and paginated it in the other document so you can only insert the pages you can't reflow the text into your main document.

Comment: Yeah, I understood that. Thanks for the help